# SwiftUI overlay cancels touches

Tags: swiftui

I have a button and I'd like to put a semi-transparent gradient overlay on top of it.

```
Button(action: {
  print("Pressed")
}) {
  Text("Press me")
}
.overlay(
  LinearGradient(
    gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, Color.black.opacity(0.3)]),
    startPoint: .top,
    endPoint: .bottom
  ).disabled(true)
)
```

Even though the gradient has `disabled(true)` it still eats the touches and doesn't forward them to the actual button. `.allowsHitTesting(false)` provides the same result.

Any idea what can be wrong?

*Note: I know I can put the overlay just to `Text("Press me")` but I don't want it. (This is just example code showcasing the problem)*

---

**Edit:** This issue is solved in Xcode 11.2 ✅

Comment: You created a gradient view in front fo your Button which has no user interaction to go through to your Button. Instead of .overlay , use .background or add .onTapGesture after .overlay.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following code works on Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

```
struct TestButtonWithOverlay: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Pressed")
        }) {
            Text("Press me")
                .padding()
        }
            
        .overlay(
            LinearGradient(
                gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, Color.black.opacity(0.3)]),
                startPoint: .top,
                endPoint: .bottom
            )
            .allowsHitTesting(false) // !!! must be exactly here
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this works in Xcode 11.2  Thank you

Comment: FWIW this doesn't seem to work when overlaying a view on top of a scroll view; the user can't scroll.

Comment: Does not work when overlaying Text on top of TextField. When you tap the Text label, the TextField is never interacted with.

Comment: @AlanScarpa see my answer bellow for your case

Answer (score 0):

When working with a `ScrollView` the correct fix is to use the `.background` content modifier on the `ScrollView`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/background(alignment:content:)

It will as expected with your "background" appearing above the content of the `ScrollView`.

Example of using to create a shadow effect:

[image: Shadow effect via .background content modifier demonstrated]

---

Interesting note: On the simulator `.overlay` works with a `ScrollView`, but on a physical device only `.background` allows scrolling.

The physical device is on iOS 14, and the simulator is iOS 15, so it's possible it might have been a regression. Although apparently this issue dates back further than either.