# SwiftUI .onTapGesture always higher priority than .swipeActions

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How do I make my the code in `.swipeActions` be called instead of the one in `.onTapGesture`?

I have a `SwiftUI` view like follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                    .swipeActions {
                        Button(role: .destructive) {
                            print("Tapped Delete button")
                        } label: {
                            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Tapped VStack")
        }
    }
}
```

This produces an output like this:

[image]

You can see, that only the code inside of `.onTapGesture` is called. The code inside of `.swipeActions` is never called. How can I change the priority, so that the code inside of `.swipeActions` functions correctly?

Comment: Can you please tell me that why you are adding `onTapGesture` on whole `List` instead of specific row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI overlay cancels touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235820/swiftui-overlay-cancels-touches)

Comment: @HardikShekhat The code above is just a demonstration. In my specific case I would like to close the keyboard opened from a TextField when pressing anywhere on the `View`. The `View` also has a `List` with rows embedded.

Comment: @Yrb The question provided does not really answer my question. The code in `.onTapGesture` should still work.